# What is the function of 乃 in 子甫至乃去乎 ?

Tags: translation, grammar, classical-chinese

i understand: 
子甫至 - you just arrived a moment ago.
去 - go.
乎 - character that makes the sentence a question.

What is the role of 乃 in this sentence?

Comment: It means "then", "thereupon" here.

Answer (score 2):

乃, also means 就, which means "about to" in your sentence.

You arrived just a moment ago, and about to go just like that?